# Как грамотно реализовать сортировку коллекции?

Tags: java, многопоточность, сортировка

Есть простой метод сортирующий коллекцию

```
public List<User> GetOrderedUsers(){
        Collections.sort(repository);
        return repository;
    }
```

известно, что данный метод будет вызываться огромное количество раз из разных потоков(коллекция синхронизирована). Вопрос вот в чём, как сделать так, чтобы при вызове данного метода коллекция постоянна не сортировалась? Т.е. чтобы потки не занимались постоянной сортировкой, а сортировалась только тогда, когда размер коллекции менялся.

Comment: Давайте подумаем, что есть сортировка.У вас есть некий набор элементов. Вы их упорядочиваете по какому-то критерию, т.е. сортируете. Процесс занял какое-то время и расположил элементы коллекции в нужном порядке. Теперь вы пытаетесь сортировать отсортированные элементы снова. Т.е. переставить элементы в те позиции , в которых они уже находятся, т.е. по сути ничего не сделать. Конечно, при вызове метода сортировки будет осуществлен проход по коллекциии, чтобы проверить порядок элементов. Если вы и этого хотите избежать поставьте флаг boolean, который укажет, что сортировка уже выполнена

Comment: Так же есть ещё вариант пересмотреть тип контейнера - использовать `TreeSet` или `TreeMap`. Судя по названию метода - у вас там пользователи лежат, предполагаю что они все уникальные и двух одинаковых быть не может, тогда вам подойдет `TreeSet`, а учитывая что у вас многопоточный случай - `ConcurrentSkipListSet`.

Comment: Либо просто сортируйте при добавлении новых элементов, а не при получении текущих.

Comment: А вообще в этом случае совет дать сложно по той простой причине, что абсолютно не ясно, как именно задействована коллекция. Для  многопоточности есть множество ньюансов. К примеру, возможен вариант, когда коллекция сначала создается и наполняется, а уже потом используется ее содержимое. Или, к примеру, запись производится крайне редко, а чтение почти постоянно. Противоположенная ситуация, когда чтение выполняется редко, а запись постоянно. и.т.д. любой из вариантов имеет свое более оптимальное решение.